# Why is SQL server unable to connect to Azure key vault using SQL Server connector

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, tde

I am trying to encrypt sql server database in Azure VM using TDE where the EKM will use Azure Key vault. I have been following the steps outlined in below link.

[setup steps for EKM using Azure Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/setup-steps-for-extensible-key-management-using-the-azure-key-vault)

I have followed all the steps exactly including the below step where we need to provide value for SECRET (Application ID without hyphens+ Azure vault key).

```
USE master;  
CREATE CREDENTIAL sysadmin_ekm_cred   
    WITH IDENTITY = 'keyvaultname',  
    SECRET = 
 'ef509ab6e52649388e65283e9378b0a171ccf2d0a8004abbbaaf93ab8f5909c0'   
  FOR CRYPTOGRAPHIC PROVIDER AzureKeyVault_EKM_Prov;
```

I get following error when trying to run below code

```
CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY CONTOSO_KEY   
FROM PROVIDER [AzureKeyVault_EKM_Prov]  
WITH PROVIDER_KEY_NAME = 'Azurevaultkeyname',  
CREATION_DISPOSITION = OPEN_EXISTING;
```

Msg 33028, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
Cannot open session for cryptographic provider 'AzureKeyVault_EKM_Prov'. Provider error code: 3303. (Provider Error - No explanation is available, consult EKM Provider for details)

Please let me know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue, the provider tries to create a registry key but doesn't have permissions to do so, therefore it fails. Try the following steps taken from this [blogpost](https://www.visualstudiogeeks.com/devops/SqlServerKeyVaultConnectorProviderError2058RegistryConsultEKMProvider)

Open regedit

1. Navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft
2. Create a new Key called “SQL Server Cryptographic Provider” (without quotes)
3. Right click the key, from the context menu select ‘permissions.
4. Give Full Control permissions to this key to the Windows service account that
   runs SQL Server