# SQL Server Connector for Azure Key Vault with SQL 2017 Developer Edition possible?

Tags: sql-server, azure-keyvault

We're trying to test Azure Key Vault for TDE and AlwaysEncrypted and are running into issues. Before we go any further in troubleshooting, can anyone please confirm the following?

1. Can we use SQL Server 2017 Developer Edition for this test?

   - Is the SQL Server Connector compatible? (It doesn't list 2017 as a supported version)
   - We're encountering error 2058 and have tried the suggested registry fixes to no avail
2. If 2017 isn't supported, is 2016 Developer Edition possible?

Here's the recommended registry fix solution, but it still errors out for us: [Why is SQL server unable to connect to Azure key vault using SQL Server connector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48517350/why-is-sql-server-unable-to-connect-to-azure-key-vault-using-sql-server-connecto)